# How do I refresh the whole Google chart with updated data every minute using AJAX?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

Will this work for using AJAX to refresh the data and show it in the Google Chart on a webpage written in PHP? All the data is on a SQL server with different files to retrieve the data in jsonTable! They should be working fine! How do I refresh the whole chart with updated data every minute or so? Is there a better way to do this inside the setTimeout function? Currently it does not seem to be working! It draws the chart the first time when the timer runs out, but every time after that, nothing happens.

```
<?php 
    include 'sql_day.php'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//var startdate = "default";
//var enddate = "default";
var inProcess = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process..
setInterval( function () {
    if (inProcess) {
        return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call..
    }
    inProcess = true;//make it run..
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sql_day.php', //Define your script url here..
        //data: {'startdate':startdate,'enddate':enddate}, //Pass some data if you need to..
        //async: false,
        success: function(answer) {
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart, answer);//update your div with new content..
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free..
        },
        error: function() {
            //unknown error occurred..
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free..
        }
    });
}, 60000 );

function drawChart()
{
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

    var options = {
    title: 'Last 24 hours:', titleTextStyle: {color:'#8c8c8c'},
    width: '1400',
    legend: {position:'bottom', textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c', fontSize: 16}},
    chartArea: {width:'92%', height:'68%'},
    colors: ['#d7523d', '#2595ca'],
    backgroundColor: {
        fill: '#262626',
        stroke: '#8c8c8c',
        strokeWidth: '0'
    },
    hAxis: {
        textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c'},
        gridlines: {color: '#8c8c8c',
            count: -1, 
            units: {days: {format: ['MMM dd']}, hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']}}
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c'},
        gridlines: {color: '#8c8c8c'}
    }
};

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="week.php"><b>Week</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="month.php"><b>Month</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="video.php"><b>Videos</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><b>About</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section class="top-container">
            <div class="showcase"><div class="graph" id="line_chart"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

start/enddate is from an example I found elsewhere! I don't know what it does so it's just commented out.

I'll add sql_day.php (sql login info is edited out) to the post:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
$query = 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(" ", time)) AS datetime, temperatur, fuktighet
FROM sensortest WHERE time BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and now()';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
 array(
  'label' => 'Date Time', 
  'type' => 'datetime'
 ),
 array(
  'label' => 'Temperature (°C)', 
  'type' => 'number'
 ),
 array(
  'label' => 'Humidity (%)', 
  'type' => 'number'
 )
);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $datetime = explode(".", $row["datetime"]);
 $sub_array[] =  array(
      "v" => 'Date(' . $datetime[0] . '000)'
     );
 $sub_array[] =  array(
      "v" => $row["temperatur"]
     );
 $sub_array[] =  array(
      "v" => $row["fuktighet"]
     ); 
 $rows[] =  array(
     "c" => $sub_array
    );
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

When I comment out "google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);" after google.charts.load... The chart get populated after 1 minute which is 60 seconds as is defined in the setInterval function, so that means the Interval is working, however, the chart is never updated after this point.

I've edited this post to better explain the question!

============= Edit: I tried this change, but it's not working. I don't know what the start/end date is either. I would be grateful if someone were willing to help me out a bit. I'm also fresh to this so there might be more errors here.

```
<?php 
    include 'sql_day.php'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var chart_data;
    var startdate = "default";
    var enddate = "default";
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(load_page_data);

    var inProcess = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process..
    setInterval( function load_page_data() {
        if (inProcess) {
            return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call..
        }
        inProcess = true;//make it run..
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sql_day.php', //Define your script url here..
            data: {'startdate':startdate,'enddate':enddate}, //Pass some data if you need to..
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                    chart_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    drawChart(chart_data);
                }
                inProcess = false;//Queue is free..
            },
            error: function() {
                //unknown error occurred..
                inProcess = false;//Queue is free..
            }
        });
    }, 60000 );

function drawChart(chart_data)
{
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);

    var options = {
    title: 'Last 24 hours:', titleTextStyle: {color:'#8c8c8c'},
    width: '1400',
    legend: {position:'bottom', textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c', fontSize: 16}},
    chartArea: {width:'92%', height:'68%'},
    colors: ['#d7523d', '#2595ca'],
    backgroundColor: {
        fill: '#262626',
        stroke: '#8c8c8c',
        strokeWidth: '0'
    },
    hAxis: {
        textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c'},
        gridlines: {color: '#8c8c8c',
            count: -1, 
            units: {days: {format: ['MMM dd']}, hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']}}
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        textStyle: {color: '#8c8c8c'},
        gridlines: {color: '#8c8c8c'}
    }
};

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

    chart.draw(data2, options);
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: A timeout only executes once. If you want it to repeat, use setInterval instead.

Comment: I guess I have to load the file that gets the data every time? and modify drawChart?

Comment: if there is new data available on the server then you will need to re-load it via AJAX, yes.

Comment: @ADyson Is there somewhere I can learn or get an example of how that is done correctly with this page I'm designing?

Comment: You can certainly find dozens of tutorials about how to make an AJAX request. But I'm unclear specifically what issue you're having now - I see you've updated it to use an interval, but what happens when you do that? Does the code run at the specified interval? Is there a new / different problem? Are you asking how to fetch the value of `$jsonTable;` dynamically, perhaps? Please be clear and specific.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for replies! I edited the question with more info. Yes I wanna update the data in the $jsonTable from "sql_day.php" and show updates every minute in the chart! Loading the chart is working fine, but updates are not happening.